# Not understanding child_process/forking in Node.js

Tags: node.js, child-process

I have this code:

```
"use strict";

if(!process.env.CHECKDIN_AWS_KEY || !process.env.CHECKDIN_AWS_SECRET) {
    throw new Error('CHECKDIN AWS ENV vars must be set');
    process.exit();
} else {
    console.log('Starting...');
    var config = require('./config/config'),
        fs = require('fs'),
        sqsQueueURLs = config.sqs.urls,
        _ = require('underscore'),
        mildsauce = require('./lib/mildsaucedb'),
        tasks = [];

    _.each(config.sqs.queues, function(item) {
        var key = item.split("-").pop(),
            tableName = config.dynamo[key],
            params = {
                QueueUrl: config.sqs.urls[key],
                VisibilityTimeout: 60,
                WaitTimeSeconds: 20
            };

        mildsauce.readMessage(params, key, tableName);
    });

}
```

What I need to do is rewrite this so that each queue in the loop runs on its own `child_process`. I have read the NodeJS documentation on forking backwards and forwards, but can't seem to wrap my head around how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Use child_process.fork if you want to create a unique Node.js process for each queue. Using fork you can send JSON messages back and forth between the Node processes.

If the process you want to create is a non Node.js process then use the child_process.exec method. Exec takes a string representing a standard terminal command.

Comment: Hmm.. basically what's happening right now is that my SQS queues are filling up and aren't "draining" at a decent rate, so I was playing with the idea of multi-threading the SQS queue draining process, but just not sure how to do it